# Parsing time with struct gives me a .exe has stopped working error

Tags: c, time

This is the code. In this case I'm trying to print hour. Thanks in advance.

```
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        time_t stringTime;
        struct tm *t0;
        stringTime = time(NULL);
        t0 = localtime(&stringTime);
        printf("%s\n", t0->tm_hour);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `tm_hour` is an `int` and your using it as a `string`. change your code to `printf("%d\n", t0->tm_hour);`

Comment: Enable all warnings & debug info when compiling. If you had compiled with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` you would have got a warning

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that simple problem :)).

Answer (score 4):

`t0->tm_hour` is integer, so `%s` is not the correct format specifier for it. Use `%d` instead.